# plone.app.theming xi:include performance

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a complicated rules.xml - more than 600 lines - for now I have partly seperated it in several xml-Files (~ 20 xi-includes).

```
<rules css:if-content="body.template-A>
    <xi:include="template-a.xml">
</rules>
```

But this is very slow to render > 15sec on page request.

How can I speed up transformation?
Merging all  in the rules.xml is a solution, but not the preferred...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I got it right, all 600 lines on a single file are fast and when the only change is to split into different files and doing xi:include then is >15 seconds (i.e. really slow)? That seems a bug to me worth reporting on github

Comment: Its faster, yes about 1/4 -> 1/3 (~5sec) faster, with Products.LongRequestLogger

Comment: @gforcada we split up the rules for freitag as well (if I remember correctly), without any performance issues. xinclude is pretty much standard, I can't imagine that this is really the problem.

Comment: After a few more tests, i also think this couldn' be the problem, sorry about this.  
But for now I have no idea, i use ~80% css:if-content="body.template" rules, a few (~5-10) if-content="//"-XPath rules but only in css:if-content="body.template" containers....

Comment: @tisto yes I know, that's why I asked him explicitly about that just to rule out that, I guessed it couldn't be, but better ask than wonder :)

Comment: @user966660 write performance tests and play around with the if-content rules. Use xpath instead of css and try to be as specific as possible with your xpath expressions. e.g. xpath=//html/body[contains(@class, 'template-A')

Answer (score 2):

Products.LongRequestLogger is good for finding requests that take too long, it is usually the wrong tool to figure out why a certain response is slow.

Here is what you should do:

1) Set up some performance tests with jmeter (or any other performance measurement tool) for your page:

https://plone-performance-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jmeter/getting-started-with-jmeter.html

Since you already know which pages take too long to render, it might be sufficient to just write a performance test for a single page. Having tests for the different kind of pages will give you a better idea why things are slow though.

2) Run the performance tests and play around with the Diazo rules. Remove them entirely and then add parts step by step (with and without xincludes). This will show you where the rules are slow. Make sure you save the performance test results for each step to be able to compare.

3) Confirm that xincludes are the problem (or not). If this is really the case, I guess there is not much you can do about it, instead of avoiding xincludes. Though, it is hard to imagine that this is really the problem. I'm using xinclude in basically all my larger projects, where we run performance tests on a regular basis. I never saw any performance issues with it.

Comment: actually combining performance tests with P.LongRequestLogger would be quite interesting, so you don't only check which Diazo rule is slow but also see where is spending time when adding that offending rule

Comment: You can use the Zope profiler in combination with performance tests (which is what I usually do). Though, when it comes to Diazo rules you usually don't see which rules take most of the time. I tried to profile the XSLT transformation directly at some point. Though, I could never get stable measurements.